# gitlab runner and testcontainers with docker socket binding

Tags: docker, gradle, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, testcontainers

I am using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) to start a Postgresql DB for my junit test. Locally everything works fine. This is my small test project:

https://gitlab.com/janning/tpj-testcontainer

I can run the test inside my IDE and on CLI with `./gradlew test`

Now I want to run it in my Gitlab-CI Pipeline but **without** docker-in-docker (dind). So I need to mount the docker socket, which is documented here: https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/gitlab_ci/

so I configred my gitlab-runner like this:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800
[[runners]]
  name = "kt103-tpj"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "registry.gitlab.com/janning/tpj-testcontainer/debian:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    extra_hosts = ["host.docker.internal:host-gateway"]
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

First my [gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/janning/tpj-testcontainer/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml) builds a Dockerimage as I need openjdk-17 and some docker commands.

```
variables:
  TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE: "host.docker.internal"
stages:
  - dockerimage
  - test

dockerimage:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: dockerimage
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - tag=":latest"
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/debian${tag}" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/debian${tag}"

test:
  stage: test
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/debian:latest
  script:
    - echo $DOCKER_HOST
    - echo $DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
    - echo $DOCKER_CERT_PATH
    - ./gradlew test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: build/test-results/test/**/TEST-*.xml
```

The job "test" failed ([complete log here](https://gitlab.com/janning/tpj-testcontainer/-/jobs/2631908364))

> > Task :test HalloTest > test() FAILED
> > java.lang.IllegalStateException at RyukResourceReaper.java:129 1 test completed, 1 failed
> > Task :test FAILED

If i dig deeper into the junit result I can see the following [stacktrace](https://gitlab.com/janning/tpj-testcontainer/-/pipelines/571416950/test_report):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not connect to Ryuk at host.docker.internal:49158
at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.maybeStart(RyukResourceReaper.java:129)
at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.init(RyukResourceReaper.java:42)
at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:203)
at ...
```

I guess it has something to do with the docker image, which I build. But I am stuck as I don't know what the problem is. I don't how to solve or debug this situation.

The ryuk container is started in my host which is running gitlab-runner. But it can't connect:

$ docker container logs -f ba62a173aafd
2022/06/24 09:42:51 Pinging Docker...
2022/06/24 09:42:51 Docker daemon is available!
2022/06/24 09:42:51 Starting on port 8080...
2022/06/24 09:42:51 Started!
panic: Timed out waiting for the first connection
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
/go/src/github.com/testcontainers/moby-ryuk/main.go:50 +0x449

Comment: Can you use an in-memory database (SQLite, H2, HDBC, ...) instead?  My experience so far has been that testcontainers is hard to set up and requires a lot of privileges, which gets in the way of running unit tests.  This is doubly true if you need a variety of environments ("inside your CI system", "without a Docker Desktop corporate license", ...).

Comment: I dont want an in-memory db. But thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The problem was just a firewall problem blocking traffic between the docker containers. As I could reach any docker container from external, it took my quite a while until I realized it.

Comment: Hi @Janning - would you mind sharing how you did that? I am having the same problem and am looking for a good solution.

Comment: Just check your firewall

Comment: Hehe, thanks, but did you add docker0 or a static ip address to your iptables?